# Convert string type date field (dd/mm/yy hh mm ss ) to string YYYYMMDD in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, data-conversion

Example values of my feed column,

27/04/2015 00:00:01

2/2/2015  12:00:01 AM

16/03/2016 00:00:01

So far I have tried in a derived column expression ,

```
REPLACE((DT_WSTR,10)(DT_DBDATE)MyField,"-","")
```

it's casting 2/10/2020  12:00:00 AM

to 2020-02-10

but I am looking for 2020-10-02

This is little strange
[image]

This is what I expect

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What is the source? What is the datatype in the source? Why are you casting to a string? Date should be stored as dates, not strings.

Comment: store as date and then only convert on the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, I think this does what you want:

```
select convert(date, left(feed, 10), 103)
```

Comment: @Gordan Linoff , Thank you . I am using SSIS packaged, Derived column - expression

Answer (score 0):

Prior to load you can `Set DateFormat DMY`

**Example**

```
Set DateFormat DMY

Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('27/04/2015 00:00:01')
,('2/2/2015 12:00:01 AM')
,('16/03/2016 00:00:01')

Select * From @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol
2015-04-27 00:00:01.000
2015-02-02 00:00:01.000
2016-03-16 00:00:01.000
```